# Rails ActiveRecord not respecting boolean defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a User model with a `draft_record` boolean column which has a default of `true`. When creating records they are created with `draft_record`: `false` rather than `true`. This worked when the field was called draft however then the draft association and draft attribute assignment methods clashed resulting in the draft attribute being unsettable. Am I doing something wrong? I have had this problem before and just worked around it by reverting to what worked.

Ruby: 1.9.3-p327

Ruby on Rails: 3.2.12

DBMS: Postgres

Relevant migration:

```
class AddDraftColumnToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :draft_record, :boolean, default: true
    add_column :users, :draft_id, :integer
    add_column :users, :current_id, :integer
  end

  def self.down
      ...
  end
end
```

Resultant schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130303002123) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "draft_record", :default => true
    t.integer  "draft_id"
    t.integer  "current_id"
  end

end
```

Creating a user object:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
1.9.3-p327 :001 > u = User.create(name: "Jon")
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (28.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_id", "draft_id", "draft_record", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 03 Mar 2013 00:42:04 UTC +00:00], ["current_id", nil], ["draft_id", nil], ["draft_record", false], ["name", "Jon"], ["updated_at", Sun, 03 Mar 2013 00:42:04 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
 => #<User id: 1, created_at: "2013-03-03 00:42:04", updated_at: "2013-03-03 00:42:04", name: "Jon", draft_record: false, draft_id: nil, current_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p327 :002 >
```

Comment: do you have any callbacks which sets the draft record before saving it to the database?

Comment: There are no callbacks which set draft_record before saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was caused by a `default_scope` with the conditions hash set to `draft_record: false`. This forced any record being added through active record to set `draft_record` to false.

Answer (score 0):

The default value is set at DB level. So the insert query will not generate the default. Check the records inserted if they have correct default value set.

Comment: The inserted records do not have it set.

Comment: Try generating another migration of **change_default(:draft_record, true)**